# Existence of a real-valued function in two real variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does there exist a function $F:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $D(F)=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (that is, $|F(x,y)|<+\infty$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$)
such that $\lim_{|x-y|\to 0} F(x,y)=+\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for instance: 
$F(x,y)=\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ for $y\neq x$, and $F(x,y)=0$ for $y=x$